# Unsupervised Sentimental Analysis in R

Tags: r, unsupervised-learning, sentiment-analysis

How would you evaluate unsupervised sentimental analysis?

I am reading on evaluating sentimental analysis and learning that much of the classification models that are being used, the data has target/label variables. How would you evaluate a survey that is only text with no target/label variables? Right now, I am just giving the responses a sentimental score (positive/negative/neutral) but I am having trouble approaching validation with 1000+ responses. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

In a truly unsupervised setting, the only possibility is to cluster the documents. Typically this would be done with [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model). Then the result could be evaluated by inspecting the words most associated with every topic, and assign a sentiment class to the whole topic/cluster, i.e. all the documents labelled with it.